# Query with the many-to-many set (joined table) in the WHERE clause

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, hql

For example, I have the mapping file like this

```
   <class name="my.test.model.Product" table="PRODUCT">
    ...
            <set name="retailers" table="product_shop" lazy="false">
                <key column="PRODUCT_ID" />
                <many-to-many column="SHOP_ID" class="my.test.model.Shop" />
            </set>
    ...
    </class>
```

Now I want to query the Products of a particular Shop A. Something like this come to mind:

```
String searchHql = "select p from Product p inner join p.retailers retailing where p.retailers.shop_id = :shopId";

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Product> productList = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(searchHql ).setInteger("shopId", shopId).list();
```

But it won't work. The error returned is:

could not resolve property: shop_id of: my.test.model.Shop. I have searched a lot, but still not find the right way to access the "many-to-many" subset in hql. Is this possible? Or I need to map the Product_Shop table to a model class?

**UPDATE**: as it seems there's no other way, I end up mapping Product_Shop into a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to use the alias you assigned to the joined entity in the wgere clause:

```
select p from Product p inner join p.retailers retailing 
where retailing.shop_id = :shopId
```

Side note: you should respect the Java naming conventions: `shopId` rather than `shop_id`.

Comment: unforturnately, shop_id is the column name. My model "Shop" has its ID as "id" (same as Product), so when I use "retailing.id", it uses the "id" of "Product" instead.

Comment: HQL queries never use table and column names, but always use entity and field/property names.

Comment: yes, but this time there are duplicate between 2 property names in a joined table..